# Error when updating system

Tags: 16.04

When I update my system, I got a problem, which is

```
Err:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wallch/wallch-daily/ubuntu xenial/main Sources
  404  Not Found
```

[image: Error in terminal when updating the system]

The output of Software Updater is:

[image: Error in software updater]

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: If you look at the contents of the folder in the link you provided, you'll see that xenial isn't supported yet - at least on that link.

Comment: @anonymous2 Ok. Please suggest me  the steps so that I will not see this message again.

Comment: Could I suggest that we work this out in chat?

Comment: Just enter the chat box https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41957/ask-anonymous2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:wallch/wallch-daily
```

Then run:

```
apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```